# Win32 API multithreading to play .wav file with no lag

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, delay, wav

I am trying to play a .wav sound in my Win32 API pong game. When one paddle shoots a 'fireball' at the other I want to play the .wav file, however everything stops for the duration of the sound. I would like to use multi-threading to solve this problem.

The way that I am attempting to solve this makes no difference:

Thread creation and function call:

```
std::thread t1(&Game::PlayFire, this);
t1.join();
```

Playsound Function:

```
void Game::PlayFire()
{
PlaySound(TEXT("fireball.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
}
```

I am really just looking for the std::head solution to this, however any possible answers are appreciated.

Thanks!
Shane

Comment: Replacing 

    t1.join();

with 

    t1.detach();

works, however I'm not sure if this is safe. I thought I'd post it in case someone else has this problem and I don't receive more knowledgeable help than what I can scrape out of Google. 
More help is definitely appreciated but this is a somewhat serviceable solution, provided I am not missing something.

Comment: Don't you just need to pass `SND_ASYNC` as a flag?

Answer (score 0):

The call to t1.join prevents the immediate thread from continuing execution until t1 is complete

Comment: Thanks, that's a start. I honestly assumed that as the main game thread still pauses. That is why I am looking for a solution or guidance towards one.

Comment: To spell this out a bit more, there's no point in launching a separate thread to call PlaySound() if the first thing you're going to do is wait for that thread to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using std::thread::detach (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach).

Comment: Ah, I just posted this in a comment from the original question. I believe this works for me, I will mark the question as answered in a few hours just to make sure that this is an appropriate solution with no downsides.